# Moving Rows in Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted to know the difference between these. The `tableView` method & the `UITableViewController` method.

```
tableView.moveRow(at:, to:)      
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

Wanted to know the difference and when to use them, cause I used the `tableView.moveRow(at: SourceIndexPath, to: DestinationIndexPath)` inside the `tableView(tableView:, moveRowAt:, to:)`. But the App crashes.

Would appreciate the help.

Crash Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (1 moved in, 0 moved out).

Comment: Could you paste the crash / error message. Your cells rely on the data source, so your model should be reflective of this. Are you using `NSFetchedResultsController` ?

Comment: No not using fetchController.

Comment: Paste the error / crash

Comment: okay added the crash error

Comment: Read the error message closely "...  plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section.."

Comment: Error tells you enough information about what is wrong. Your model isn't reflective of your change.

Comment: This must be an issue from unmatched visible cells and data source order. Once you move a cell via gesture or code(`tableView.moveRow(at: to:)`, you need to update your data source as well.

Answer (score 0):

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)`

This is the delegate method of table view. It is asking the view controller tasks to perform.

Meanwhile
`tableView.moveRow(at:, to:)` is the method programatically to move row. You are calling `tableView.moveRow(at:, to:)` in the delegate method causing the next changes before one change is done.